# If version of the artifact id is not changed, will the dependent project pick up the latest changes

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have two maven projects p1 and p2.  p2 is dependent on p1.
now if I do some code changes in project p1 and without changing the version of artifact publish it to repository, will the
p2 project will pickup the latest changes.

or do I need to change the version in p1 and update the same in p2 in dependency configuration to pickup the latest changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the **version** on p1: if it is **SNAPSHOT** (e.g. 1.0-SNAPSHOT), then you can re-build p1, the artifact will be deployed to your local repo and maven gets from there the most-updated version (so you do not need to change anything/do not have to checkout pom.xml). This mode (SNAPSHOT) is good for development.

But if do not work with snapshots, meaning you are in "production"/"release" mode, maven will not fetch the most updated p1 from local repo. So you will have to change the version in p1's pom.xml, and then consume it from p2 respectively.

HTH